# SQL summary with highest price and total qty

Tags: sql

have the following table and data

```
partno price qty    
A0001  10     2
A0001   8     6
A0001  15     10
```

How can I issue a query to get the following result

```
partno.   price.   qty. 
A0001     15       250
```

unique partno, highest price in the list and sum(qty )* highest price.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: When you tag the correct RDBMS, please do make sure you include your attempt(s) too please.

Answer (score 0):

A simple aggregation shows the result you want:

```
select
  partno,
  max(price) as max_price,
  max(price) * sum(qty) as total
from t
group by partno
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Just replace "Table_Name" with your first table's name in the database */
select 
   distinct 
      partno, 
      max(price) price, 
      max(price) * sum(qty) qty 
from 
   Table_Name 
group by 
   partno
```

Comment: Although this code snippet may answer the question, including an explanation of *why* and *how* it helps solve the problem improves the quality and longevity of your answer. See ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).